# Is TCP better than UDP for multi-threaded servers?

Tags: udp, client-server

If I was to implement a server to handle multiple clients connecting simultaneously would it be better to use TCP?

Not taking efficiency into account (I know know UDP is quicker, but unreliable).

In UDP you can't have sockets for each client connection?
Because in UDP the socket is identified by only the destination port number (right?).

In Java, I know it is easy to create a multi-threaded server to handle multiple clients at the same time in TCP. But can it be done in UDP? I imagine that it would be very complicated.

I'm just trying to get an understanding of UDP here (I don't want to actually implement anything).

Comment: Why should it be any harder with UDP? And what's your definition of "better" while "not taking efficiency into account"?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of server you are developing. If you need your clients to stay connected and ready to receive data from server(for example a push service) you should implement it using TCP. If you want to implement a simple request-response service, then UDP is better choice.

Comment: Also, can your clients easily deal with lost messages? UDP doesn't guarantee delivery, so the client must figure out if a message was lost and deal with it. TCP guarantees delivery.